# How to vectorize computation on arrays of different dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some large numpy arrays of complex numbers I need to perform computations on.

```py
import numpy as np

# Reduced sizes -- real ones are orders of magnitude larger
n, d, l = 50000, 3, 1000

# Two complex matrices and a column vector
x = np.random.rand(n, d) + 1j*np.random.rand(n, d)
s = np.random.rand(n, d) + 1j*np.random.rand(n, d)
v = np.random.rand(l)[:, np.newaxis]
```

The function is basically `x*v*s` for each row of `x` (and `s`) and then that product is summed across the row. Because the arrays are different sizes, I can't figure out a way to vectorize the computation and it's way too slow to use a for-loop.

My current implementation is this (~3.5 seconds):

```py
h = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    h.append(np.sum(x[i,:]*v*s[i,:], axis=1))

h = np.asarray(h)
```

I also tried using `np.apply_along_axis()` with an augmented matrix but it's only slightly faster (~2.6s) and not that readable.

```py
def func(m, v):
    return np.sum(m[:d]*v*m[d:], axis=1)

h = np.apply_along_axis(func, 1, np.hstack([x, s]), v)
```

What's a much quicker way to compute this result? I can leverage other packages such as dask if that helps.

Comment: How about `h2 = ((x * s).sum(axis=1)[:,None] * v.T); np.allclose(h, h2) >>> True`

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a speed tool; just a convenience (in some cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With broadcasting this should work:

```
np.sum(((x*s)[...,None]*v[:,0], axis=1)
```

but with your sample dimensions I'm getting a memory error.  The 'outer' broadcasted array `(n,d,l)` shape is too large for my memory.

I can reduce memory usage by iterating on the smaller `d` dimension:

```
res = np.zeros((n,l), dtype=x.dtype) 
for i in range(d): 
    res += (x[:,i]*s[:,i])[:,None]*v[:,0]
```

This tests the same as your `h`, but I wasn't able to complete time tests.  Generally iterating on the smaller dimension is faster.

I may repeat things with small dimensions.

This probably can also be expressed as an `einsum` problem, though it may not help with these dimensions.

---

```
In [1]: n, d, l = 5000, 3, 1000 
   ...:  
   ...: # Two complex matrices and a column vector 
   ...: x = np.random.rand(n, d) + 1j*np.random.rand(n, d) 
   ...: s = np.random.rand(n, d) + 1j*np.random.rand(n, d) 
   ...: v = np.random.rand(l)[:, np.newaxis]                                                           
In [2]:                                                                                                
In [2]: h = [] 
   ...: for i in range(len(x)): 
   ...:     h.append(np.sum(x[i,:]*v*s[i,:], axis=1)) 
   ...:  
   ...: h = np.asarray(h)                                                                              
In [3]: h.shape                                                                                        
Out[3]: (5000, 1000)
In [4]: res = np.zeros((n,l), dtype=x.dtype) 
   ...: for i in range(d): 
   ...:     res += (x[:,i]*s[:,i])[:,None]*v[:,0] 
   ...:                                                                                                
In [5]: res.shape                                                                                      
Out[5]: (5000, 1000)
In [6]: np.allclose(res,h)                                                                             
Out[6]: True
In [7]: %%timeit  
   ...: h = [] 
   ...: for i in range(len(x)): 
   ...:     h.append(np.sum(x[i,:]*v*s[i,:], axis=1)) 
   ...: h = np.asarray(h) 
   ...:  
   ...:                                                                                                
490 ms ± 3.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [8]: %%timeit 
   ...: res = np.zeros((n,l), dtype=x.dtype) 
   ...: for i in range(d): 
   ...:     res += (x[:,i]*s[:,i])[:,None]*v[:,0] 
   ...:                                                                                                

354 ms ± 1.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [9]:                                                                                                
In [9]: np.sum((x*s)[...,None]*v[:,0], axis=1).shape                                                   
Out[9]: (5000, 1000)
In [10]: out = np.sum((x*s)[...,None]*v[:,0], axis=1)                                                  
In [11]: np.allclose(h,out)                                                                            
Out[11]: True
In [12]: timeit out = np.sum((x*s)[...,None]*v[:,0], axis=1)                                           
310 ms ± 964 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Some time savings, but not big.

And the `einsum` version:

```
In [13]: np.einsum('ij,ij,k->ik',x,s,v[:,0]).shape                                                     
Out[13]: (5000, 1000)
In [14]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,ij,k->ik',x,s,v[:,0]),h)                                            
Out[14]: True
In [15]: timeit np.einsum('ij,ij,k->ik',x,s,v[:,0]).shape                                              
167 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Good time savings.  But I don't know how it will scale.

---

But the `einsum` made me realize that we can sum on `d` dimension earlier, before multiplying by `v` - and gain a lot in time and memory usage:

```
In [16]: np.allclose(np.sum(x*s, axis=1)[:,None]*v[:,0],h)                                             
Out[16]: True
In [17]: timeit np.sum(x*s, axis=1)[:,None]*v[:,0]                                                     
68.4 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@cs95 got there first!

As per @PaulPanzer's comment, the optimize flag helps.  It's probably making the same deduction - that we can sum on `j` early:

```
In [18]: timeit np.einsum('ij,ij,k->ik',x,s,v[:,0],optimize=True).shape                                
91.6 ms ± 991 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This seems to be one of the cases where the `optimize` flag actually helps: `np.einsum('ij,ij,kl->ik',x,s,v,optimize=True)` is twice as fast on my rig. But `np.outer(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',x,s), v)` is still faster.

Comment: Enjoyed reading the thought process behind the gradual optimization of this operation. The `einsum` trick is pretty nice as well.

Comment: What are my options if the computation is `np.sum(np.sin(x[i,:]*v)*s[i,:], axis=1)` and I can't rely on the x*s optimization?